# How can I read a line and Declare Variables named after the read values c#

Tags: c#

I am kind of new here while sneaking around for ages stealing all your helpful suggestions.

Today though I am kind of not finding any solution so I have to ask.

I am writing a tool that reads from a document, line by line. The First Line is a header. Now, this tool is supposed to work regardless of how many columns the read document has and I want it to create extra variables for extra columns.

For example, My default version accounts for 14 Columns each referring to a Weekday (so we have 2 Mondays, 2 Tuesdays, etc.)

What I did not account for was the fact that later on along the roads I might find documents with 3 Mondays or even more.

My goal now is to read the first line (containing the header) and define Variables based on that. Essentially Read the header and for every value (split by `;`) I want it to create a new variable (string).

Once I then reach the next line, I want the values written into the corresponding variables (so IDK Monday 1 = read value 1 and so on.

Any suggestions on how I can declare variables ... well essentially dynamically?

Sorry for typos and whatnot, I am not an English native.

EXAMPLE HEADERS FOR N=9 POSSIBLE VALUES PER DAY:

> WPNummer     ;WPText     ;WPBezeichnung     ;TpMo1     ;TpMo2     ;TpMo3     ;TpMo4     ;TpMo5     ;TpMo6     ;TpMo7     ;TpMo8     ;TpMo9     ;TpDi1     ;TpDi2     ;TpDi3     ;TpDi4     ;TpDi5     ;TpDi6     ;TpDi7     ;TpDi8     ;TpDi9     ;TpMi1     ;TpMi2     ;TpMi3     ;TpMi4     ;TpMi5     ;TpMi6     ;TpMi7     ;TpMi8     ;TpMi9     ;TpDo1     ;TpDo2     ;TpDo3     ;TpDo4     ;TpDo5     ;TpDo6     ;TpDo7     ;TpDo8     ;TpDo9     ;TpFr1     ;TpFr2     ;TpFr3     ;TpFr4     ;TpFr5     ;TpFr6     ;TpFr7     ;TpFr8     ;TpFr9     ;TpSa1     ;TpSa2     ;TpSa3     ;TpSa4     ;TpSa5     ;TpSa6     ;TpSa7     ;TpSa8     ;TpSa9     ;TpSo1     ;TpSo2     ;TpSo3     ;TpSo4     ;TpSo5     ;TpSo6     ;TpSo7     ;TpSo8     ;TpSo9     ;UsedInPstamm

After Reading that Line I want to create Variables, that for each NEW line will write the Values from the Below example to the corresponding variable, do something with it (not relevant), clear it again and go for the next line. I already have the part to read -> do something -> clear -> read next line. I just don't want to Hardcode like billions of variables to read differnt documents.

Within a Single Document the Headers will always stay the same, but as soon as the Next Document gets read, the Headers might get more or Less (mostly in the "TpXxn" areas. If there is a TpMo8 there will also be a TpSo8, as each Line is supposed to represent a Shift system for working hours up to n different possibilities per week.

EXAMPLE VALUES FOR ONE LINE OF N=9 OPTIONS PER DAY:

> 1;Keine ZZ;Keine Zeitzählung;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2|3|7|11|15|20|21|26|37|39

Formatting of this looks kinda strange here. I don't know why.

The amount of TpMo-TpSo can vary from 1 to n, this is a rather full file going up to n = 9.

The code I use to "analyze" this in my initial version was just using a simple Line.Split()

```cs
        var data = Line.Split(';');
        var WPNummer = data[0];
        var WPText = data[1];
        var WPBezeichnung = data[2];
        var TpMo1 = data[3];
        var TpMo2 = data[4];
        var TpDi1 = data[5];
        var TpDi2 = data[6];
        var TpMi1 = data[7];
        var TpMi2 = data[8];
        var TpDo1 = data[9];
        var TpDo2 = data[10];
        var TpFr1 = data[11];
        var TpFr2 = data[12];
        var TpSa1 = data[13];
        var TpSa2 = data[14];
        var TpSo1 = data[15];
        var TpSo2 = data[16];
```

What I am now looking for is a way for my Code to realize that there are n TpMo, TpDi, etc. and not only 2, as defined by me in my initial tool which only accounted for 2 Columns without headers at all.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You need to show input file and what variables you want to create. I think you don't need variables, just a `List` to read lines. Do lines repeat? Or is it single/multiple blocks consisting of several lines what cause the troubles?

Comment: Indeed, a `List<>` or perhaps a `Dictionary<,>` or `Dictionary<, List<>>` of some type of class. A sample of the file and your actual code may help to help you.

Comment: C# doesn't execute dynamically created code. Once compiled, you can't add new code at runtime, so what you are asking is simply impossible. You can make use of some collection, like `List` or simple array `string[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `Dictionary` or `List<(string, object)>`/`List<ValueTuple<string, object>` which allows you to access the keys which are the names and the value. Replace the `object` type argument with your wanted type (or `dynamic` if you need it.)
It seems from your question that you need to assign many variables in one, this is ass simple as making the type `List<(string, List<string, object>)>` Assigning the variables after reading is as simple as

```cs
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("yourfile.txt") //or any specific reader for a file format you're using
{
    string varname;
    theDict[varname = sr.ReadLine()] = theType.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
    //OR
    theList.Add((varname = sr.ReadLine(), theType.Parse(sr.ReadLine()));
    //the Type can of course be a List<(string, object)>
    string s;
    while((s = sr.ReadLine()) == "YOURENDSTRINGHERE") //or another condition you want
    {
        //read and assign as above
        //if you're using a list in a list, simply use
        theList[varname].Add((sr.ReadLine(), theType.Parse(s));
    }
}
```

You can also use casting (`(theType)sr.ReadLine()`) if it's supported by the type and it works for you.